# Adobe Native Extensions -- not working?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flex4.5

I am trying to work with "Adobe Native Extensions" - one of the newest features released in Adobe Flash Builder 4.5. I am trying to communicate between Adobe AIR and a native C++ application on Windows 7 with the help of Adobe Native extensions. (Of course, we can do this today with NativeProcess APIs, but ANE is much more powerful)

I followed the steps mentioned in the following article:
http://thingsico.de/blog/tag/native-extensions/

1. created the sample DLL using cygwin to compile the C++ code (integrated the `FlashRuntimeExtensions.h` and `FlashRuntimeExtensions.lib` during compilation)
2. built the sampleANE using the following command line.

   `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\sdks\Air3.0_flex4.5.1\bin\adt" -package -storetype pkcs12 -keystore "certs\vlabCert.p12" -target ane "TestSampleANE.ane" "bin\extension.xml" -swc "bin\SampleAne.swc" -tsa none -platform Windows-x86 -C "bin"`

I faced a small problem here w.r.t. timestamp, which I navigated by adding `-tsa none` to the above command. I was able to successfully generate the `HelloAne.ane`

3. I created a new sample Flex Project, and included the `TestSampleAne.ane` and `SampleAne.swc` in the lib files of the project. I was able to successfully access the `SampleAne` object, as well its public functions in the ActionScript code, and could successfully compile the application. However, when I try to launch the application, it gives me the following error:

```
Process terminated without establishing connection to debugger.

Not supported native extensions profile

Launch command details:  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\sdks\Air3.0_flex4.5.1\bin\adl.exe" -runtime "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\sdks\Air3.0_flex4.5.1\runtimes\air\win" E:\ANE\SampleAirProject\bin-debug\SampleAirProject-app.xml E:\ANE\SampleAirProject\bin-debug
```

At first, I thought that the problem is due to the fact that I was using Flash Builder 4.5, and not 4.5.1 (which is what Adobe recommends for working with ANE). So, I downloaded the patch and upgraded it. I even checked that I have AIR 3.0 runtime on my machine. But even then the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adding `-profile extendedDesktop` to launch command or the following line to application descriptor XML file (`application.xml`)

```
<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop</supportedProfiles>
```

fixed this error for me.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Project/Properties/Flex Build Packaging tab, then click Native Extensions tab and checked the Package box that is been in your native extension's line. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

(For some reason I can't add a comment to ask you, but) Are you running Flash Builder on 32 bit or 64 bit? I think adl won't support 64 bit

Comment: Hi K2xl....thanks for the comment....I am running on 64 bit.....what I also just figured out was that the above error was because the support for launching ANEs is not yet there in FB 4.5.....and will only be available from FB 4.6....so I guess that might be the reason for this problem !!

Comment: @KapilKaushik suddenly i find myself having this exact problem. keep getting "Not supported native extensions profile" grrrr